# How can i load laravel sessions in ratchet?

Tags: laravel, ratchet

I installed Ratchet on Laravel, it's work, but I can't read user sessions.
I read this - https://laravel.io/forum/01-16-2015-loading-laravels-session-using-ratchet 
But it doesn't work and I have an error:

> An error has occurred: Undefined property: stdClass::$request

I think that it can be related with new version of ratchet, because decision that described on topic which I cited above published in 2015
My code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Classes\Sockets;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use App\Classes\Sockets\BaseSocket;
use App;
use Auth;
use Config;
use Crypt;
use Illuminate\Session\SessionManager;
class ChatSocket extends BaseSocket {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
         $session = (new SessionManager(App::getInstance()))->driver();
         $cookies = $conn->WebSocket->request->getCookies();
         $laravelCookie = urldecode($cookies[Config::get('session.cookie')]);
         $idSession = Crypt::decrypt($laravelCookie);
         $session->setId($idSession);
         $conn->session = $session;

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {

    $from->session->start();
    // do what you wants with the session 
    // for example you can test if the user is auth and get his id back like this:
    $idUser = $from->session->get(Auth::getName());
    if (!isset($idUser)) {
        echo "the user is not logged via an http session";
    }
    // or you can save data to the session
    $from->session->put('foo', 'bar');
    // ...
    // and at the end. save the session state to the store
    $from->session->save();
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem after applying the same code ( found it on [this page](https://laravel.io/forum/01-16-2015-loading-laravels-session-using-ratchet) ).

The problem here is with this line:

```
$cookies = $conn->WebSocket->request->getCookies();
```

replace it with the following:

```
$cookiesRaw = $conn->httpRequest->getHeader('Cookie');
$cookies = [];
if(count($cookiesRaw)) {
    $cookies = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\parse_header($cookiesRaw)[0]; // Array of cookies
}
```

of course you have to install the **GuzzleHttp** package first... use the following command to install it

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```